# Linux Mint 18.3, black screen after booting

Tags: linux-mint

I have LINUX Mint 18.3 KDE 64-bit, with Linux 4.10.0-38-generic. Unfortunately after some installing of python packages and update && upgrade, when I am restarting my systems stops after grub on black screen and nothing happens. I am able to enter in recovery mode and tryed to make update && upgrade once again but did not help. Could somebody suggest how I can find the problem and how to solve it?

result of command "lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'" :[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the black screen is caused by the video drivers getting stuck somewhere.  If this is the case, you will still see your cursor, but everything else is black.  If the python upgrade changed a file that is used by the video driver,  and the fix recommended by [Al-Mothafar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765965/al-mothafar) doesn't fix it, here are the steps that I've used when the black screen happened to me:

1. When the GRUB menu pops up, use the arrow keys to highlight the Linux OS, but do not press enter.
2. Press the "e" key to enter the terminal.
3. find the line that includes the words "quiet splash" and use the arrow keys to get there.
4. After "quiet splash", type "nomodeset" and then press control-x to reboot.
5. The computer should reboot and go to the login page.
6. Login like normal.
7. If the issue is with the video drivers, the black screen should not occur after successfully logging in. There might be a prompt saying that the video drivers need to be updated.  Whether or not the message comes up, update the video driver now either through the prompt or by going to the menu and clicking on Driver Manager.  A restart is necessary to complete the update.
8. After the restart, login like normal and everything should be back to normal.  That is, if the black screen was caused by the video drivers being hung up for some reason.

There may be other ways to fix the black screen problem, but this is what I've used every time (including 5 minutes ago while writing this answer).  If you think the issue is caused by something else, you may want to check if there is a solution more specific to your issue.  As far as I know, nomodeset shouldn't harm the computer since all it does is start the OS without turning on the video drivers.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the history file, `/var/log/apt/history.log`, I have found that `liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.18.3-0ubuntu1.1)` was deleted by apt-get auto remove.
    Then Reinstall it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

After trying too many things, I ran a Dell diagnostic (f12 at startup) on the memory.  Sure enough, I found a bad DIMM.  Removed it, and everything else cleared up immediately.